# Follow Path with Shrinkwrap Modifier

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves, constraints, shrinkwrap

I'm trying to use a Follow Path Constraint on a Curve that is being Shrinkwrapped to a surface.

When the Curve's Shrinkwrap Modifier is active, the object with the Follow Path Constraint is still following the unmodified curve as can be seen in these screenshots (it doesn't move when the modifier is active):
[image: Shrinkwrap]

How can I get the object to follow the path after the Shrinkwrap modification? Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the shrinkwrap modifier to act on the spline rather than the geometry:

[image]

Notice the tooltip.

Edit: I expected my mouse cursor to show up, but it didn't.  The "affect splines" button is the first button to the right of the Shrinkwrap modifier's name.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer: it works! I don't entirely understand the `Apply on Spline` option. What geometry would the Shrinkwrap be acting on if it's a Curve?

Comment: If you give it bevel or extrusion, it has actual mesh.  If you don't apply on spline, the spline (for purposes of a few things, like follow path) won't be affected by the modifier, but that generated mesh will be.

Comment: Thank you very much, Nathan. :)